# After computer restart, 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' : Keyset does not exist

Tags: c#, x509certificate, private-key, system.security

I am using following code to sign the data:

```
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp;

        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
        {
            if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
            {
                csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            }
        }
        csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

First time after installing the certificate to my local machine works fine but when I try to sign after the computer restarting it throws an exception. What could be the possible reason, please help.

Comment: Does anywhere in your code set something like `csp.PersistKeyInCsp = false`?  If so, it's when that object gets disposed.

Comment: No, Computer without restarting works fine, but after restart problem occurs, Is it disposed when system restart ?

Comment: Installing certificate on current user instead of Local machine worked for me, but installing on local machine occurs same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. IIS Express running in my account was able to access the private key of the certificate on the day I was importing it on the local machine but not after a restart. The way I was able to fix was by explicitly grant full rights to my account in the **certlm** console (even thou my account was already in the local administrators group which had full-rights on that private key).